# Django Rest Framework ManyToMany field ordering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got the following models:

```
class BusStop(m.Model):
    street_name = m.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['street_name']
    ...

class Carrier(m.Model):
    name = m.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class CarrierStop(m.Model):
    bus_stop = m.ManyToManyField(BusStop, related_name='carrier_stop_fk')
    carrier = m.ForeignKey(Carrier, on_delete=m.CASCADE, related_name='test_carrier_fk')
```

I made the serializer:

```
    class CarrierStopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        carrier = serializers.StringRelatedField()
        bus_stop = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

             class Meta:
                    model = CarrierStop
                    fields = ['id', 'carrier', 'bus_stop']
```

I've got some objects of BusStop models and serializer gives representation like this:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "carrier": "Fremiks",
            "bus_stop": [
                    "Armii Krajowej",
                    "Kino Lot 01",
                    "Kosynierów I 02"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

bus_stop field from CarrierStopSerializer returns bus stops ordered by name. I want to order it by id in intermediate table carrierstop_bus_stop created by Django ManyToMany field. I know that i should use SerializerMethod field instead of StringRelatedField(or PrimaryKeyRelatedField, doesn't matter) but I'm not sure how to do this exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as

```
class CarrierStopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    carrier = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    bus_stop = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_bus_stop(self, model):
        return [bus_stop.__str__() for bus_stop in model.bus_stop.all().order_by('id')]

    class Meta:
        model = CarrierStop
        fields = ['id', 'carrier', 'bus_stop']
```